# IndexError: list index out of range in opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv3.0, face-recognition

I have this piece of code that detects a face and saves it as jpg file. But as I compile this program I get an error `IndexError: list index out of range`
Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import sys

imagePath = sys.argv[1]

image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.3,
    minNeighbors=3,
    minSize=(30, 30)
)

print("[INFO] Found {0} Faces!".format(len(faces)))

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

status = cv2.imwrite('faces_detected.jpg', image)
print("[INFO] Image faces_detected.jpg written to filesystem: ", status)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facecrop.py", line 4, in <module>
    imagePath = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: how did you compile / run the script?  It needs a location of the image file to read

Comment: am using visual studio code

Comment: change this line imagePath = sys.argv[1] to imagePath = '<dir>/<image.jpg>'

Comment: it worked but other error :(  'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facecrop.py", line 13, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor' '

Answer (score 0):

You can not run this script with IDLE.

You need to give arguments by your terminal

Example:

```
python3 yourfilename.py /path/to/imagePath.png
```

or you can change your code to this:

```py
import cv2 import sys

if len(sys.argv)>=2:
    imagePath = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print("Write your image's path!")
    exit()

image = cv2.imread(imagePath) gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml") faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=3, minSize=(30, 30) )

print("[INFO] Found {0} Faces!".format(len(faces)))

for (x, y, w, h) in faces: cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

status = cv2.imwrite('faces_detected.jpg', image) print("[INFO] Image faces_detected.jpg written to filesystem: ", status)
```

But the second one will only do not give error and warn you. First one is important and you need to do it each time you run your code.

If you don't want to do these, you need change your code to this: (Replace your image's path with "yourimagepath")

```
import cv2 import sys

if len(sys.argv)>=2:
    imagePath = sys.argv[1]
else:
    imagePath = "yourimagepath"

image = cv2.imread(imagePath) gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml") faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=3, minSize=(30, 30) )

print("[INFO] Found {0} Faces!".format(len(faces)))

for (x, y, w, h) in faces: cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

status = cv2.imwrite('faces_detected.jpg', image) print("[INFO] Image faces_detected.jpg written to filesystem: ", status)
```

Comment: Make sure you properly format your code (make sure statements start on a new line).  Though your answer is valid the code you pasted and the bottom would error out, thus overall your answer is bad.

Comment: I think it is fine

Comment: Even that `print` on the last line?

Comment: Ok, i will change.

Comment: Also PEP recommends that `for` statements and `if` statements be multi-line. (though this is not a rule it is the recommendation). "Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged."

Comment: It worked! But another error :(    ...  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facecrop.py", line 13, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor' `